# printing a web page after loading?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php & MySQL to develop my web based HRM system. Iam genarating leave report then i need to get printout automatically after loading full report (without opening print dialog box .)

this is possible or not?
thanks;

Comment: Yes with a Java applet included on the page. This should help you http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialWebApplet

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that this is not possible within the context of a web page. If you design a (browser) plugin, then you can use the plugin to do so, but all users would need to install this plugin for it to work.